# Is there a way to have 2 php files for a drop down menu

Tags: php, html

I have created a drop down menu in html using JavaScript. Now I have to use PHP. I'm not too familiar with PHP, but I have been researching and hit keep hitting bumps.
This is the code I have

```
  <form action="" method="GET">
  <select name="Choose" id="Choose">
  <option value="generalfeedback"<?php if ($row[Choose] == 
  'generalfeedback') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>General 
  Feedback</option>
  <option value="helprequest"<?php if ($row[Choose] == 
  'helprequest') 
  echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Help Request</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
    <?php
  //loadPage.php
  $requested_page = $_GET['selectedPage'];

  switch($requested_page) {
  case "generalfeedback":
  header("http://cdlwebsysdev.esc- 
  atsystems.net/SRomero/module5/generalfeedback.php");
  break;
  case "helprequest":
  header("http://cdlwebsysdev.esc- 
  atsystems.net/SRomero/module5/helprequest.php");

  }
  ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is your problem? I do not understand what do you want to achieve, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Here is something similar to your needs. Please have a look:

```
<?php
//loadPage.php
if( !empty($_GET['Choose']) ){
    $requested_page = $_GET['Choose'];
    switch($requested_page) {
        case "generalfeedback":
            header("Location: http://cdlwebsysdev.esc-atsystems.net/SRomero/module5/generalfeedback.php");
            //break;
            exit();
        case "helprequest":
            header("Location: http://cdlwebsysdev.esc-atsystems.net/SRomero/module5/helprequest.php");
            //break;
            exit();
    }
}
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!--Resource Files (if any)-->
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="GET">
        <select name="Choose" id="Choose">
            <option value="generalfeedback"<?php if(isset($_GET['Choose']) && $_GET['Choose']=='generalfeedback') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>General Feedback</option>
            <option value="helprequest"<?php if(isset($_GET['Choose']) && $_GET['Choose']=='helprequest') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Help Request</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

To redirect the page please read documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php);

Comment: I have used this code before it wont load the selection chosen. Ty

Comment: Hey Steve, try adding `Location: ` with the `header()` function  like `header('Location: https://google.com')`

Comment: Hi Reza thank you I just tried it and it loops back in to the same page this is what i received in the address bar http://cdlwebsysdev.esc-atsystems.net/SRomero/mod5/mainphp.php?Choose=contactform.php&submit=Submit#

Comment: is it possible to add two form action for the drop down menu? This is the form action i currently have at the moment <form action="#".

Comment: You can submit the form to 2 different locations using JavaScript as well

Comment: I know I have use javascript but this project is for homework and the instructor wants this in php. I was researching would i need to use a sql database to make this possible.

Comment: SQL database will not help in any way! However, I tried the above solution and it is working from my side :) Make sure that you have all of the above code posted by me remains in a single file (after PHP block add HTML)

Comment: Reza thank you very much it does work I wasn't refreshing my file in my ftp. Thank you again